# Starting oracle rac node2 error: ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Synchronization Service

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rac

I have a oracle RAC /12c/. I got these error when I try start the base from node2.

````
```ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

ORA-01565: error in identifying file '+DATA/mydborcl/spfilemydborcl.ora'

ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +DATA/mydborcl/spfilemydborcl.ora

ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Synchronization Service```
````

I am very new to oracle. How can I start the mount the database on node2 and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> `ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Synchronization Service`

You need to make sure the the Grid Infrastructure services are started first. They provide all of the networking and ASM storage for the cluster, and you can't start a database instance without them.

On Linux, as root, run `crsctl start crs`

The command `crsctl stat res -t` should show you the state of all cluster services.

Comment: command not found on oralinux

Comment: You might have to go looking for it if it isn't in the default root $PATH. Typically, Oracle products are *not* added to the default path. Use the `find` command to search for it, or look in the same general directory tree where your Oracle database software is installed; there should be a product directory tree for Grid Infrastructure (e.g. "grid1").

Comment: It would be installed in a dedicated location, not in a home directory. A common first level directory would be /u01, but there is no hard and fast rule. Check your $ORACLE_HOME location for clues. If you didn't install this software yourself, get help from your DBA.